# How to send contents of a queue to elasticsearch index with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a logstash up and running that consumes two rabbit queues and sends to an elasticsearch. This is my logstash.conf file:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    host => 'rabbit'
    durable => true
    user => 'user'
    queue => 'dev-user_trace'
    password => 'pass'
  }
  rabbitmq {
    host => 'rabbit'
    durable => true
    user => 'user'
    queue => 'min-price-queue'
    password => 'pass'
  }

}
filter{
}
output{
  stdout { codec => json}
    elasticsearch{
    hosts => ["elasticsearch"]
    index => "eventss-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }

}
```

Now I have another queue, but I want to send its content to a different elasticsearch index. My question is: how do I need to redirect specific entries to an specific index? Or do I need another logstash instance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good start. Now you simply need to "type" each input and then forward the events to the appropriate output given its type, like this:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    host => 'rabbit'
    durable => true
    user => 'user'
    queue => 'dev-user_trace'
    password => 'pass'
    type => 'traces'               # <-- add this
  }
  rabbitmq {
    host => 'rabbit'
    durable => true
    user => 'user'
    queue => 'min-price-queue'
    password => 'pass'
    type => 'prices'               # <-- add this
  }

}
filter{
}
output{
  stdout { codec => json}

  if [type] == 'traces' {          # <-- check type
     elasticsearch{
       hosts => ["host1:9200"]
       index => "index1-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
     }
  }

  if [type] == 'prices' {          # <-- check type
     elasticsearch{
       hosts => ["host2:9200"]
       index => "index2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
     }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The above is the most general approach so that you can configure both outputs differently. As suggested by @pandaadb, you can also have a single output and define a type that would be your target index:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    host => 'rabbit'
    durable => true
    user => 'user'
    queue => 'dev-user_trace'
    password => 'pass'
    type => 'index1'                    # <-- add this
  }
  rabbitmq {
    host => 'rabbit'
    durable => true
    user => 'user'
    queue => 'min-price-queue'
    password => 'pass'
    type => 'index2'                    # <-- add this
  }

}
filter{
}
output{
  stdout { codec => json}

  elasticsearch{
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"   # <-- use type here
  }
}
```

Comment: If you call your type by the index name, you can use a wildcard in your index and have 1 elasticsearch output that indexes to "%{type}-%{+YYYY/MM.dd}"

Comment: @pandaadb Yes, but he might want to configure both ES outputs differently, like sending to two different ES hosts (like in my answer). My answer is more general, but of course, you can have a single output and define the `type` to be the target index, if needed. I've updated my answer and given you credit for that.

Comment: Oh yes your answer is definitely correct :) I just wanted to add that on because it helped in my simple case and it makes the config more readable I think

Comment: Thanks for your response. Perfectly explained an clear. Kudos for you