# How sync data from mysql database to elasticsearch with logstash: only indexing new data and index by country?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

Can I specify the Id where  starting syncrhonize? For not index all data again and can I specify diferent index in diferents scenarios, for example, index by country?
This is my logstach conf:

```
# file: contacts-index-logstash.conf
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/peter/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost/MYJOBS"
    jdbc_user => "readuser"
    jdbc_password => "xxxx"
#    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT af.IdAnuncio as idanuncio, af.Titulo, af.Descripcion, af.Empresa, p.Abreviatura, 
        pr.Nombre as Provincia, cd.Nombre as Ciudad, af.Localidad
            FROM  `ANUNCIO_FORM` af
            INNER JOIN PAIS p ON p.Id = IdPais
            INNER JOIN PROVINCIA pr ON pr.Id = af.IdProvincia
            INNER JOIN CIUDAD cd ON cd.Id = af.IdCiudad
            WHERE af.IdAnuncio >0
            AND af.Fecha_de_publicacion >  '2016-12-01'
            AND af.Estado =1"
  }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
    elasticsearch {
        index => "anuncios"
        document_type => "internos"
        document_id => "%{idanuncio}"
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

PD. English not is my first language, so please excuse any mistakes.

Comment: si puedes explícame en español qué es lo que estás intentando hacer porque no entiendo bien lo que quieres decir.

Comment: These answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608084/how-to-send-contents-of-a-queue-to-elasticsearch-index-with-logstash/38608294#38608294 + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503809/logstash-input-jdbc-is-duplicating-results/32503984#32503984

Comment: Thank you @Val, I will to try.

Comment: Hi. I changed my file in output part:
<pre><code> 
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
    elasticsearch {
        index => "vacante_%{countryabbr}_%{+YYYYMMdd}"
        document_type => "internos"
        document_id => "%{id}"
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
}
</code></pre>
I created the index by the  country code and the date.
Thank you.